# High-current analog switch

Tags: relay, analog-switch

I'm looking for an SPST analog switch (or alternative device) capable of handling >=150mA (5VDC) across its switch, controllable by a logic-high signal. I've been looking on digikey, and haven't had much luck finding anything capable of handling more than 25mA (it's also been tough as there doesn't seem to be a way to filter by current/power rating).

Thank you very much for your help!

**EDIT**:
Thank you all for the help and suggestions!

Umar: No, I meant capable of handling at least 150mA

mkeith: I'm actually rethinking my design, so I won't bother posting my very rough draft schematic

Alex Hajnal: I hhd tried that on Digikey but with no success, thanks for the mouser suggestion!

Transistor: Yea I realize my typo, that's what happens when I try to do stuff quickly late at night ;)

Comment: Current rating did you mean less than or equal to?

Comment: Can you show how you will use it in a schematic? There is a possibility that what you really need is not what you think you need. For example, would a load switch do what you want? That is a category of IC you can search for. But it connects a voltage rail to a load. It is not EXACTLY the same as an analog switch.

Comment: Try including the phrase "High current" in your parametric search.  [This Maxim part](https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/256/MAX4655-MAX4658-1515602.pdf), for example, is rated up to a maximum (do-not-exceed) continuous current of ±300mA.

Comment: Standard terminology is "current **through** a switch" and "voltage **across** a switch. You wouldn't say "water flow across a pipe".

Comment: FYI, responses added to post

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is just an example. You can search based on your requirements in the same fashion in digikey or mouser. Please post a new specific question if you are still stuck.
TS5A12301E from TI. 
http://www.ti.com/switches-multiplexers/analog/products.html#p480=1;1&p3139max=271.987;450

[image]

Current rating is upto 450 mA

[image]

Answer (score 1):

try this

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fSXElO.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Please explain about its working and ports

Comment: probably about 20 mA into the base; for 150mA Ic, only need beta of 7.5, so the bipolar should be well saturated with low Vce. The OFF bipolar merely needs the base lowered to +4 volts; taking the OFF base to 0volts will stress the reverse-breakdown of base-emitter, so I'd suggest just dropping to +3 or +4volts.